# When to use Starling or is it needed?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, starling-framework

In publishing to iOS using AIR I consistently notice I can max out frame rates at 60fps WITHOUT ever having to use Starling, ie using GPU render mode.

Since coding to Starling framework is a LOT more cumbersome I am wondering when it would ever be necessary to use.

Can anyone enlighten me or provide specific examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application needs to run on all types of resolution or all types of devices like all IOS and Android, my suggestion is to use starling framework. I hope this one line would clear your doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Specific examples are hard to find, but obviously you are not taxing the device hard enough for proper hardware acceleration to matter. I assume you are testing on an actual device when you get 60 fps, and not just in the simulator?

Comment: see this bench mark as well http://esdot.ca/site/2012/performance-showdown-starling-vs-nd2d-vs-genome2d-vs-haxe-nme

Comment: GPU mode for mobile sure seems to be far better evolved than the desktop/web counterpart, so if you are only targeting mobile, I can't really find a good reason to do it differently.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need GPU acceleration on slower devices than a 4th generation iPad. For example I suggest to try your app on an iPhone 4 to see if it still runs at 60 fps. If not you might want to take advantage of the GPU acceleration Starling offers.